# couldn't start zookeeper server in vagrant ubuntu box due to insufficient memory error

Tags: java, java-8, apache-kafka, vagrant, apache-zookeeper

I've vagrant box with below ubuntu configurations.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Below are the memory details -

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            488          43          92           1         351         414
```

I've downloaded the file `kafka_2.12-1.1.1.tgz` from [here](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads).

Then I'm trying to start zookeeper server after extracting the archive using below command.

```
$ sudo /home/vagrant/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  /home/vagrant/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000e0000000, 536870912, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 536870912 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/vagrant/hs_err_pid5404.log
```

I've provided the complete error log [here](https://gist.github.com/rajcspsg/012cea280fba96b692f386d6738d7e45).

I see always the vagrant machine has the swap space problem.
How can I solve this problem and install successfully in vagrant machine.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to show your Vagrant file but the default VM memory space is not enough to start Zookeeper, let alone Kafka as well as Zookeeper.

Assuming your host machine has at least 4G of memory, you can take a look at the Vagrant + Ansible repo that I've forked from Confluent that by default, will start Zookeeper and Kafka on separate machines.

https://github.com/cricket007/cp-ansible/blob/addVagrant/vagrant/README.md

Comment: cricket_007 - My configuration looks fine. I got the error when I implemented the platform using ubuntu OS earlier. When I changed the ubuntu/xeniel to centos/7 it works fine. I think I need to tweak the swapiness configuration of ubuntu. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't want swap in Kafka or Zookeeper, but something like `config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo vm.swappiness = 1 >> /etc/sysctl.conf"`. I've only tested my code in CentOS, actually, even though I added support for other Vagrant boxes